# How to avoid duplicates in list python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, duplicates

So, i created a list of dictionaries with the following values :

```
itemlist = [
    {
        'Index': '1',
        'Name': 'a',
        'Price': 79,
    },
    {
        'Index': '2',
        'Name': 'b',
        'Price': 20,
     }]
```

I also created a function as such:

```
def createItem():

    new = {}
    new['Index'] = input("Enter the index of the new : ")

    for i in range(len(itemlist)):
        if itemlist[i]['Index'] == new['Index']:
            print(f"{itemlist[i]['Index'] } already exists!")
            break
       
        else:
            new['Name'] = input("Enter the name of the item: ")
            new['Price'] = float(input("Enter the price of the " + new['Name'] + " : "))
        i+=1
    itemlist.append(new)
```

So, what i wanted to do was that if the index is already in the list of dictionaries, it cannot add a new item with same index and will just break out from the loop. It works for the first index but doesn't work for the other indexes despite `new['Index']` is the same as the one already in the list. It would still go to else block despite already existing in the list. There are no errors in the terminal but the function still is not working as i intended. **I am trying to make the item index to be unique so that each dictionary will have different index no duplicates**. Anyone that can help?

EDIT : Thank you so much for those who helped me solve the problem! I appreciate your help :)

Comment: What is the reasoning to do `i+=1` inside loop?

Comment: your `else` doesn't make sense to me... you need to iterate through the whole list before you ask for the rst of the input.

Comment: Anyway, you almost certainly should just be using a dictionary here, not a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a separate list to store all existing index(s) and make reference check to the list. Use a `while-loop` for input, and exiting it (`break`) only if the input is not found in the reference list.

```
itemlist = [
    {
        'Index': '1',
        'Name': 'a',
        'Price': 79,
    },
    {
        'Index': '2',
        'Name': 'b',
        'Price': 20,
     }]

def createItem():
    idx_list = [dic['Index'] for dic in itemlist]
    new = {}
    
    while True:
        new_idx = input("Enter the index of the new : ")
        if new_idx not in idx_list:
            break
        print(str(new_idx), "already exists!")

    new['Index'] = new_idx
    new['Name'] = input("Enter the name of the item: ")
    new['Price'] = float(input("Enter the price of the " + new['Name'] + " : "))
    itemlist.append(new)

createItem()
print(itemlist)
```

Output

```
Enter the index of the new :  1
1 already exists!
Enter the index of the new :  2
2 already exists!
Enter the index of the new :  3
Enter the name of the item:  new item
Enter the price of the new item :  100
[{'Index': '1', 'Name': 'a', 'Price': 79}, {'Index': '2', 'Name': 'b', 'Price': 20}, {'Index': '3', 'Name': 'new item', 'Price': 100.0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just make some changes in your code :**

1. Take a input in local variable instead of new['Index'] because if condition is not satisfied don't add this. But can remove this duplicate but it is not memory efficient .

**UPDATE:**

```
new['Index'] = input("Enter the index of the new : ")
```

**TO:**

```
inp = input("Enter the index of the new : ")
```

---

```
def createItem():

    new = {}
    while True:
        print('--------------------------')
        inp = input("Enter the index of the new : ")
        if int(inp) < 0:
            break
 
        elif any([1 for item in itemlist if item['Index'] == inp]):
                print(f"{inp} already exists!")
        
        else:
                new['Index'] = inp
                new['Name'] = input("Enter the name of the item: ")
                new['Price'] = float(input("Enter the price of the " + new['Name'] + " : "))
                itemlist.append(new)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
--------------------------
Enter the index of the new : 1
1 already exists!
--------------------------
Enter the index of the new : 2
2 already exists!
--------------------------
Enter the index of the new : 3
Enter the name of the item: a
Enter the price of the a : 12
--------------------------
Enter the index of the new : 3
3 already exists!
--------------------------
Enter the index of the new : -1
[{'Index': '1', 'Name': 'a', 'Price': 79}, {'Index': '2', 'Name': 'b', 'Price': 20}, {'Index': '3', 'Name': 'a', 'Price': 12.0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
itemlist = [
    {
        'Index': '1',
        'Name': 'a',
        'Price': 79,
    },
    {
        'Index': '2',
        'Name': 'b',
        'Price': 20,
     }]

new = input('enter a new index: ')

exists = any([1 for item in itemlist if item['Index'] == new])
print("already exists: ", exists)
if not exists:
    itemlist.append({'Index': new})

print(itemlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try `any`:

```
def createItem():
    new = {'Index': input("Enter the index of the new : ")}
    if any(new['Index'] == i['Index'] for i in itemlist):
        print(f"{new['Index']} already exists!")
        return
    new['Name'] = input("Enter the name of the item: ")
    new['Price'] = float(input("Enter the price of the " + new['Name'] + " : "))
    itemlist.append(new)
```